# What conclusions can be drawn from the CMB TE polarization spectrum?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

Does the polarization spectrum TE measured by the Planck and WMAP satellites show evidence for superhorizon fluctuations at low multipoles and are these evidence for pre-bigbang inflation?